# Select input type text from the next div's child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little html code:

```
<!-- one -->
<div id="parent-one">    
    <div id="head-one">
        <!-- some code here -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='x' name='name'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- two-->
<div id="parent-two">
    <div id="head-two">
        <!-- some code here -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='y' name='name'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the `input` text is inside a `child` that has as parent the next div after a div with an `id`. Is there a way to get the `input` value without setting up an `id` for itself based on `head-n` id?

I have `parent-x` divs and I could set an `id` for each `input` but then I guess - not sure - I would have to define a variable that contains the `input` value `x` times -foreach `id` and I would like to avoid that.

So far I tried this:

```
//head-x being either one of those head divs
var test = $('#head-x').next('div').find('input:text').val();
```

```js
//head-x being either one of those head divs
var test = $('#head-two').next('div').find('input:text').val();
console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- one -->
<div id="parent-one">
  <div id="head-one">
    <!-- some code here -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type='text' value='x' name='name'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- two-->
<div id="parent-two">
  <div id="head-two">
    <!-- some code here -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type='text' value='y' name='name'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want this value? I mean why do you need to fetch the value of next input from the previous parent?

Comment: is there any trigger point on which you want to read the input value?

Comment: i need to send that value trough ajax to a `php` script - that happens onclick on `head-x`.

Comment: Read all the inputs through script, you know who the parent is so simply deduce the next input and voila, you've got your value.

Comment: Hey @DoctorLouie, thank you for taking time to answer! I don't know their parent i mean their parent is a child of the next div that's clicked - i hope it makes sense X_X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this comment...

> I need to send that value trough ajax to a php script - that happens onclick on head-x

So you already have a click handler for the Ajax...

From what I see, you could make a good use of the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and the "begins with" operator `^=`.

And then, use `$(this)` instead of `$("#head-one")` or `$("#head-two")`.

```js
$("[id^='head-']").on("click",function(){
  var inputValue = $(this).next().find("input").val();
  console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```css
[id^='parent']{
  padding:1em;
}

[id^='head']{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- one -->
<div id="parent-one">    
    <div id="head-one">
        Click on the "head-one"!
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='x' name='name'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- two-->
<div id="parent-two">
    <div id="head-two">
        Click on the "head-two"!
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='y' name='name'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `id` use `class` and You can bind click event handler and read input value from next div.

```js
$(function(){
  $("div.head").on("click", function(){
      var $next = $(this).next();
      var value = $next.find('input[type=text]').val();
      console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-one">    
    <div class="head">
        Head 1
        <!-- some code here -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='x' name='name'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- two-->
<div id="parent-two">
    <div class="head">
         Head 2
        <!-- some code here -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='y' name='name'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```